# Accounts hijacked after open wifi network. What now?

Tags: security, internet

So I have been informed that I am sending spam email from my gmail account. I'm currently abroad and I have connected to several insecure connections.

What should I do now to restore security to my accounts? Change passwords?

EDIT:
I am not actually sending from my own account. The person who got the spam mail has my name set as sender. The actual sender email is a `.nl` account and I am currently in Miami, FL.

EDIT2:
I have accessed the networks with my Android phone, all with stock apps (they should use SSL), and my google account has 2 factor authentication.

EDIT3:
All the recipients in the mail are my contacts in my phone. I just realized that after taking a closer look at the screenshot that was sent to me. See below.

I also realized that I set up my new MBP in the hotel room on their wifi (which requires authentication from a browser). I authenticated with google (with 2 step verification) in OSX to sync contacts etc.

[image]

Comment: From what you said, it may be your 'name' is used as the "From" field. Unfortunately there is nothing you can do about this. Anyone can say ... "Barack Obama" while having ortix92@gmail.com .. there is not much you can do except warn all in your contact to double check the sending email, and not simply trusting the 'name' shown.

Comment: If your account is setup with 2-factor authentication then your account *hasn't been hijacked*.  If they are not actually using your account to send the spam, are you sure this notification, is trustworthy?

Comment: @Ramhound It is trustworthy because the mail was sent to my cousin and the other recipients were all my other contacts. No clue how that got out.

Comment: @Ortix92 - As others have pointed out email can appear to be from anyone the author wants it to appear to be sent from.  Unless this email was actual sent by your account then the information was spoofed and since you have a 2-factor authentication its very unlikely that happened.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm still a bit worried about the fact that the spammer got a hold of my contacts. How could that have happened? Maybe my contacts got intercepted during a, probably insecure, sync to one of my devices.

Comment: @Ortix92 - You should still change your password.

Comment: @Ramhound that's the first thing I did ;) I'm just wondering how my contacts have been intercepted.

Answer (score 1):

Google has a page about this ([here](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/50270?hl=en)) that can help you further; it contains some very good advice.

In general for compromised email accounts:

- Make sure you have a secure connection.
- Change your passwords and consider turning on 2-factor-authentication.
- Change any other place where you use the compromised password.
- Check for any filters, signatures, rules, forwarding, out-of-office notifications, etc. that someone could have left.
- Notify anyone that could have been affected (check your sent items and/or notify every one of your contacts)
- Check your sent items and spam for suspicious accounts that might have been created with your email account and notify the support staff of those services.

**Note** that the above actions apply for compromised email accounts; **not** for compromised computer accounts and/or computers.

---

*Edit:* if your email address is used in the "From:"-field of a spammer (and your account itself is not compromised) there is little you can do.